# Needs help with numerical analysis programming

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms

I'm trying to implement, in Matlab, the following methods for root finding:

Fixed point iteration with g(x) = x-αf(x)
Newton's method,
The secant method,
Steffensen's method.

For f(x)=x^2+x-1, with x0 = 1

However, since I haven't used Matlab before, my loops for each algorithm are full of bugs. Can someone please show me a correct way to do them?

Comment: @Moo Yes I did, but still feel very confused. Some of them construct a matrix for the loop, and others didn't.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roots_of_a_function

Answer (score 0):

I quickly threw together a code that uses Newton's method, I hope it's correct. In any case you should be able to see how the syntax of Matlab works.

```
f = @(x) x^2 + x -1; % function
df = @(x) 2*x + 1;   % derivative needed for newtons method

e = 10^-7;           % error margin
x = 0;               % initial value

n = 0;               % number of iterations

while abs(f(x)) > e  % apply newton's method until error small enough
    x = x - (f(x)/df(x));
    n = n+1;
end

fprintf('root: %i\n', x)
fprintf('number of iterations: %i\n', n)
```